# Why is copy O(n) when most hash table operations are O(1)

Tags: python

A dict is essentially a hash table, most of whose operations are in O(1). And yet Copy is in O(n). Why?

Comment: If the table has n entries, you need to do c*n operations in order to copy it, where c is some constant. What's so weird about that?

Comment: Have you searched about it? if Yes can please tell us how it went?

Comment: Hmm, could it be because accessing each of the _n_ elements (each in O(1)) yields O(n) ( = n * O(1))?

Comment: @timgeb Why are most hash table operations O(1)

Comment: @lanardo Because that's the entire point of a hash table. I won't do your homework for you.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you did not make any effort to educate yourself on how a hash table works, so I won't put any effort in an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most operations are O(1) because they're accessing the hash table and that's amortized constant time. Copy copies N elements to a new dictionary so it's O(N).

What is a hash? Ever found a file that had a small hash next to it? That identifies the file. Instead of this big file as identification, there's this short string that identifies it. You basically run a large file/string into a hash function and out pops a smaller string. It's the classical pigeonhole problem. Say you have N pigeons and N-1 holes. One hole will have 2 pigeons. In other words you will have collision. However if you use a good enough hash function, the chances of collision happening are lower than a meteorite striking you on any given day. An example would be SHA 256.

Same thing applies to a hash table. You take an item, run it through a hash function, and it places that item into a specific part of the hash table.

Which goes onto the next part 0(1) for accessing elements. Say you want to get a particular item. The hash table will take that item, run it through the hash function that it used earlier to store it, obtain the location of the place instantly and directly access it. It's constant as a result.